# How to extend BaseModel and have it return data in an associate array?

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm trying to write a model class that extends BaseModel and has a method that performs this query:

"SELECT `fruit_id`, `fruit_name` FROM `fruits` ORDER BY `fruit_name` DESC"

Here is the code it is associated with:

```
class BaseModel
{
        protected static $db_conn;

        protected static function &db()
        {
                if (empty(BaseModel::$db_conn))
                {
                        BaseModel::$db_conn = @new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
                        if (BaseModel::$db_conn->connect_error)
                        {
                                die('Connect Error: ' . BaseModel::$db_conn->connect_error);
                        }
         }
         return BaseModel::$db_conn;
       }
}
```

So how do I write a model class that extends BaseModel and has a method that performs the SELECT query I listed above, and how can I have that method return the data in an associative array using fruit_id as the key and fruit_name as the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have something like this :

```
class FruitModel extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'fruits';

    public function getAll()
    {
        $res = static::db()->query("SELECT fruit_id, fruit_name FROM {$this->table} ORDER BY fruit_name DESC");

        $res->data_seek(0);
        $result = [];

        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $result[$row['fruit_id']] = $row['fruit_name'];
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```